# How do I check if a specific date is in a week using jquery?

Tags: jquery

`reportdate` and `_paystartdate` are two date variables in my jQuery function where `_paystartdate` is date from which pay period starts from and `reportdate` is a date for single day. Now I need to check if `reportdate` is in first week of `payperiod` that means `reportdate` should be between `_paystartdate` and `_paystartdate+6`. How do I achieve this?

```
var _paystartdate = $('[id$=hdnPayPeriodStartDt]').val();
var reportdate = $('[id$=datepicker]').val();
```

Comment: If you have complicated date/time manipulations, maybe you should consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com). Check [an example answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219623/moment-js-only-within-the-last-week).

Answer (score 0):

You will not need to use jQuery to perform this comparison. Just pure javascript.

If we start with your code

```
var _paystartdate = $('[id$=hdnPayPeriodStartDt]').val(); 
var reportdate = $('[id$=datepicker]').val();
```

We then need to convert to Date types, like this:

```
var payStartDate = new Date(_paystartdate);
var reportDate = new Date(reportdate);
var payEndDate =  payStartDate.setDate(payStartDate.getDate()+6); //payEndDate should now been 6 days after payStartDate
```

now we can compare them appropriately

```
if (reportDate >= payStartDate && reportDate <= payEndDate) {
   //report date is between pay start date and pay end date
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I'll try this one. I hope this should work.  I have another column in table which accepts hours. Now I should add only those hours which are in the particular week.var _paystartdate = $('[id$=txtHours]').val(); Please help me. Let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: what does txtHours go to? paystartdate and/or reportdate?

Comment: its value for each day in the week. i have multiple rows of hours but i need to sum only the values of hours in between payperiodstartdate and payperiodstart+ 6 that means frst week of payperiod. generally payperiod is biweekly

Comment: if you provide more info in your question, like the html table you have and what you want for output then maybe I can give you a better answer.

Comment: reportdate value is in "dd/mm/yyyy" format and paydates are in Sat Dec 14 00:00:00 EST 2013 format..how do I compare this

Comment: @user3154990 - as simple as creating a date object with them, like this `new Date("Sat Dec 14 00:00:00 EST 2013)`. Once they are all date objects, then you can compare (<=>) away.